# Extracting bibliography from aux file in order of citation

Tags: sorting, bibtool

I am trying to extract a bibliography from my `.aux` file and have done so successfully with `bibtool -x file.aux > file.bib`. However, I would like the bib file to have the entries in the order of reference/citation, rather than its default order that is the same as the original BibTeX file. Does anyone know how to do this with `bibtool` or with some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - use the `bibexport` tool. It extracts in order of citation.
Usage is just `bibexport <file.aux>` and it produced `bibexport.bib`.

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify *how* one uses this tool.